# .htaccess rewriterule affected css path

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im not sure if the title is correct. I have a .htaccess file with 2 `RewriteRule`'s.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) user.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^success/message/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) successful_register.php?user_username=$1&user_activate_url=$2
```

And that is my html file (`successful_register.php`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Peter</title>
    <?php
        include("backbone/include_header.html");
    ?> 
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        include_once("backbone/navigationbar.html");
    ?>
</body>
```

I can open this file on two ways

1. `http://localhost/fragen/success/message/asdasdasd/0ab605102670807b661d9a1a4e6187`
2. `successful_register.php?user_username=username&user_activate_url=0ab605102670807b661d9a1a4e6187`

`include_once("backbone/navigationbar.html");` works!, but `include("backbone/include_header.html");` not.

Inside of `include("backbone/include_header.html");` is

```
<link href="style/css/general.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

If I use the console on the page I see this:

[image]

my folder structure:

[image: image2]

Only on this page it dont work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to include the `header` removing the underscore of its name? Try it like this: `includeheader.html`

Comment: I found the problem... . I have to change the path of the .css file to `href="../../../style/css/general.css"`, but thanks for your help!

Comment: That's fair enough! You virtually added some new levels trough `.htaccess` file, it makes sense @Name

Comment: You can use `<base href="/">` or `<base href="http://www.example.com/">`  in the **head** section of your site and that should allow you to use the relative links.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used the `<base>` tag, now it works.